# Is it possible to condition less variables according to scope?

Tags: html, css, sass, less

#### I have two sets of variables:

```css
// first
@main: blue;
@secondary: pink;

// second
@main: orange;
@secondary: red;
```

#### and I have the following html:

```html
<div>
  <div class="foo">
    <h1>FOO</h1>
    <div>
      <p>some text</p>
      <a href="#">even a link</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="bar">
    <h1>bar</h1>
    <div>
      <p>some text</p>
      <a href="#">even a link</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

- I want to assign the first set of vars only to `.foo` and all of its children.
- I want to assign the second set of vars only to `.bar` and all of it's children.

So that I could do something like:

```css
p {
  color: @secondary
}
```

And the resulting `<p>` text would be colored pink if the `<p>` is a child (or nested indirectly) of `.foo` but red if it is the child (or nested indirectly) of `.bar`.

Is that possible?